# jQuery tab not working properly when clicking

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm creating a tab using jQuery and it needs to be clickable when clicking the other tab. But it's not working properly and I have an issue with my code. I tried to look for other solutions but still did not work. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code.
https://codepen.io/christine-tine27/pen/poRxeYJ

```js
    $('.tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('.tabs div .tabs div').hide();
    $('.tabs div:first .tabs div').show();
    $('.tabs ul li').click(function(){
    $('.tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.tabs div .tabs div').hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    return false;
    });
```

```css
.tabs ul li {
display: inline-block;
}
.tabs li a {
background: #937638;
padding: 10px;
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
}
table, td, th {  
border: 1px solid #ddd;
text-align: left;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}
th, td {
padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabs" class="tabs">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#4">4-Bedroom</a></li>
      <li><a href="#3">3-Bedroom</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="4">
      <div id="tabs" class="tabs">
         <ul>
            <li class=""><a href="#2021">2021</a></li>
         </ul>
         <div id="2021" class="2021">
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <th>Firstname</th>
                  <th>Lastname</th>
                  <th>Fee</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Peter</td>
                  <td>Griffin</td>
                  <td>$100</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Lois</td>
                  <td>Griffin</td>
                  <td>$150</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Joe</td>
                  <td>Swanson</td>
                  <td>$300</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Cleveland</td>
                  <td>Brown</td>
                  <td>$250</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="3">
      <div id="tabs" class="tabs">
         <ul>
            <li class=""><a href="#2021">2021</a></li>
         </ul>
         <div id="2021" class="2021">
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <th>Firstname</th>
                  <th>Lastname</th>
                  <th>Savings</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Peter</td>
                  <td>Griffin</td>
                  <td>$100</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Lois</td>
                  <td>Griffin</td>
                  <td>$150</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please elaborate more on your issue.

Comment: Hi, My issue is when I click the second main tab the content doesn't show up, and when I click back to the first main tab It wasn't clickable anymore.

Comment: The first thing that caught my eye. The line `activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href')` returns `href`'s value like `#2021`. Are you sure the next line is correct: `$(activeTab).fadeIn();`?

Comment: You have the same ID and href for both tabs...change to : <ul>
            <li class=""><a href="#2022">2022</a></li>
         </ul>
         <div id="2022" class="2022"> and it will work

Comment: @Svela I've changed it. But still doesn't work

Comment: @ChristineSalazar I've made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wrosqjd3/

Comment: thank you @Svela. But Sorry the main tabs are the 4-Bedroom and the  3-Bedroom tabs. Not the year tab. 
I need to display the year tab and the table after clicking on the main tab.

Comment: I suggest you look for a nested tabs script. A single set of tabs is not terribly complicated. Nested ones require considerably more work and more finite traversals

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you are looking for nested tabs.

```js
$('.tabs ul li').click(function() {
  $('.tabs > ul > li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  const parent = $(this).closest('.tabs');

  parent.find('.content').hide();
  var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  parent.find(activeTab).fadeIn();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.tabs ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

.tabs li a {
  background: #937638;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: left;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabs" class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#4">4-Bedroom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3-Bedroom</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="4" class="content">
    <div id="tabs" class="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li class=""><a href="#2021">2021</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="2021" class="2021 content">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Fee</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Peter</td>
            <td>Griffin</td>
            <td>$100</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Lois</td>
            <td>Griffin</td>
            <td>$150</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Swanson</td>
            <td>$300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cleveland</td>
            <td>Brown</td>
            <td>$250</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="content">
    <div id="tabs" class="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li class=""><a href="#2021">2021</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="2021" class="2021 content">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Peter</td>
            <td>Griffin</td>
            <td>$100</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Lois</td>
            <td>Griffin</td>
            <td>$150</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```